# How to use Context API with useParams

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have an api with details of a farm and I want to show them in different components using an id. Like the data is used in many components and I want to use Context API to display the data in the components.

So here is the code that fetches the data

```
let navigate = useNavigate();
const [farm, setFarm] = useState('');
const { username } = useParams();
const { farmId } = useParams();
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
const user = React.useContext(UserContext);

useEffect(() => {

    let isMounted = true;

    axios.get(`/api/farm/${username}/${farmId}`).then(res => {
        if (isMounted) {
            if (res.data.status === 200) {
                setFarm(res.data.farm);
                setIsLoading(false);
                console.warn(res.data.farm)
            }
            else if (res.data.status === 404) {
                navigate('/');
                toast.error(res.data.message, "error");
            }
        }

    });

    return () => {
        isMounted = false
    };
}, []);
```

The username is okay because I will use the user context to get the user details.
Now, how do Use this from a context into the components, because I have tried, and it is not working.

Comment: You want to use your farm data in other components ?

Comment: Yes. I want to use the farm data in other components

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it by adding another context for farm.

Your context file:

```js
export const FarmContext = React.createContext();

export function FarmProvider({ children }) {
  const [farm, setFarm] = useState();

  return (
    <FarmContext.Provider value={{farm, setFarm}}>
      { children }
    </FarmContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

And instead of this:

```js
const [farm, setFarm] = useState();
```

Use this:

```js
const { farm, setFarm } = useContext(FarmContext);
```

Answer (score -1):

Include setIsLoading and setFarm into your dependency array. The dispatch function changes during a re-render. In your case, during development double renders components to detect issues with state management.

```
useEffect(() => {
   ....

}, [ setIsLoading, setFarm]);
```

Comment: It's not the answer of the question. It's an improvement.

Comment: You want farm data to be a in context?

Comment: Oh sorry I'm not the questioner.

Comment: Yes, I want the Farm Data to be in the context